# What's the "fastest" way to take a screenshot of a specific window under Linux programatically?

Tags: linux, screenshot

Language doesn't matter, libraries either, I just need the fastest way specifying the window (title or handle).

Answer (score 7):

Try:

```
import // man import for options
```

To take a snapshot of my pidgin client.

```
import -screen -window Kompislista foo.jpg // Kompislista is in swedish.
```

You can specify a lot of options, such as frame or window id.

Comment: `xwininfo -display :0` can be used to find the window name and id.

Answer (score 2):

see man xwd

xwd takes screen snapshots

Comment: Thanks for the info, import is part of imageMagick if I'm not mistaken but xwd is native to linux and also can take a screenshot of a different workspace if I did read correctly.  I tought using xlib and/or opengl directly could have been faster but I didn't found any information about that.

Comment: Now I'm facing the problem where xwd doesn't work if the window is partially offscreen :(

Comment: @Mike I thought i saw someone write "Language doesn't matter, libraries either"...

Comment: @Anders, yes I did say that, I tought a native application could be faster but I guess I was wrong...

Comment: I didn't think any program could get a snapshot of an offscreen (portion of a) window.

Comment: Well.. if you look at Compiz, they can actually do that but they don't provide any documentation unfortunately :\

Answer (score 0):

take a look at gnome-screenshot also.

```
   gnome-screenshot --help
```

You can take the active window screen shot with -w option.